# Black boxes instead of images in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm putting up a website using Ruby on Rails, Twitter Bootstrap, Masonry JS plugin for pinterest like layout and I'm stocking the pictures on Parse.com

Chrome and Firefox work fine so far, but Safari sometimes just displays black boxes instead of the images. Is does it with the same images all the time.

[image]

I have no idea where to start even diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

go to safari and do a right click on the black images and open element inspect. Go than to console. maybe can the console tell you what's wrong.

you can also go to inspector and maybe you see what's wrong with the images

Comment: there's nothing remarkably different from other pictures